# Count number of points in multipolygon shapefile using Python

Tags: python, geolocation, shapefile, qgis, shapely

I have a polygon shapefile of the U.S. made up of individual states as their attribute values.  In addition, I have arrays storing latitude and longitude values of point events that I am also interested in.  Essentially, I would like to 'spatial join' the points and polygons (or perform a check to see which polygon [i.e., state] each point is in), then sum the number of points in each state to find out which state has the most number of 'events'.

I believe the pseudocode would be something like:

```
Read in US.shp
Read in lat/lon points of events
Loop through each state in the shapefile and find number of points in each state
print 'Here is a list of the number of points in each state: '
```

Any libraries or syntax would be greatly appreciated.

Based on what I can tell, the OGR library is what I need, but I am having trouble with the syntax:

```
dsPolygons = ogr.Open('US.shp')  

polygonsLayer = dsPolygons.GetLayer()  


#Iterating all the polygons  
polygonFeature = polygonsLayer.GetNextFeature()  
k=0  
while polygonFeature:
    k = k + 1  
    print  "processing " + polygonFeature.GetField("STATE") + "-" + str(k) + " of " + str(polygonsLayer.GetFeatureCount())  

    geometry = polygonFeature.GetGeometryRef()          

    #Read in some points?
    geomcol = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbGeometryCollection)
    point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
    point.AddPoint(-122.33,47.09)
    point.AddPoint(-110.11,33.33)
    #geomcol.AddGeometry(point)
    print point.ExportToWkt()
    print point
    numCounts=0.0   
    while pointFeature:  
        if pointFeature.GetGeometryRef().Within(geometry):  
            numCounts = numCounts + 1  
        pointFeature = pointsLayer.GetNextFeature()
    polygonFeature = polygonsLayer.GetNextFeature()
    #Loop through to see how many events in each state
```

Answer (score 11):

I like the question. I doubt I can give you the best answer, and definitely can't help with OGR, but FWIW I'll tell you what I'm doing right now.

I use [GeoPandas](http://geopandas.org/), a geospatial extension of [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). I recommend it — it's high-level and does a lot, giving you everything in [Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) and [fiona](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fiona) for free. It is in active development by [twitter/@kajord](https://twitter.com/kajord) and others.

Here's a version of my working code. It assumes you have everything in shapefiles, but it's easy to generate a `geopandas.GeoDataFrame` from a list.

```
import geopandas as gpd

# Read the data.
polygons = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file('polygons.shp')
points = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file('points.shp')

# Make a copy because I'm going to drop points as I
# assign them to polys, to speed up subsequent search.
pts = points.copy() 

# We're going to keep a list of how many points we find.
pts_in_polys = []

# Loop over polygons with index i.
for i, poly in polygons.iterrows():

    # Keep a list of points in this poly
    pts_in_this_poly = []

    # Now loop over all points with index j.
    for j, pt in pts.iterrows():
        if poly.geometry.contains(pt.geometry):
            # Then it's a hit! Add it to the list,
            # and drop it so we have less hunting.
            pts_in_this_poly.append(pt.geometry)
            pts = pts.drop([j])

    # We could do all sorts, like grab a property of the
    # points, but let's just append the number of them.
    pts_in_polys.append(len(pts_in_this_poly))

# Add the number of points for each poly to the dataframe.
polygons['number of points'] = gpd.GeoSeries(pts_in_polys)
```

The developer tells me that spatial joins are 'new in the dev version', so if you feel like poking around [in there](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas), I'd love to hear how that goes! The main problem with my code is that it's slow.

Answer (score 4):

```
import geopandas as gpd

# Read the data.
polygons = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file('polygons.shp')
points = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file('points.shp')

# Spatial Joins
pointsInPolygon = gpd.sjoin(points, polygons, how="inner", op='intersects')

# Add a field with 1 as a constant value
pointsInPolygon['const']=1

# Group according to the column by which you want to aggregate data
pointsInPolygon.groupby(['statename']).sum()
 
**The column ['const'] will give you the count number of points in your multipolygons.**

#If you want to see others columns as well, just type something like this : 
pointsInPolygon = pointsInPolygon.groupby('statename').agg({'columnA':'first', 'columnB':'first', 'const':'sum'}).reset_index()
    
    
  [1]: https://geopandas.org/docs/user_guide/mergingdata.html#spatial-joins
  [2]: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html
```