# GeoPandas: count hexagons and lineStrings intersections

Tags: geopandas

I have a geoDataFrame *hexagons* and a geoSeries *lineStrings*. For each hexagon, I want to count how many linestrings passing this hexagon. The result should return the total number of linestrings for each hexagon (append to the hexagon table).

[image: lineStrings]

[image: hexagons]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606924/count-number-of-points-in-multipolygon-shapefile-using-python) it might help you.

The code they use:

```
import geopandas as gpd

# Read the data.
polygons = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file('polygons.shp')
points = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file('points.shp')

# Make a copy because I'm going to drop points as I
# assign them to polys, to speed up subsequent search.
pts = points.copy() 

# We're going to keep a list of how many points we find.
pts_in_polys = []

# Loop over polygons with index i.
for i, poly in polygons.iterrows():

    # Keep a list of points in this poly
    pts_in_this_poly = []

    # Now loop over all points with index j.
    for j, pt in pts.iterrows():
        if poly.geometry.contains(pt.geometry):
            # Then it's a hit! Add it to the list,
            # and drop it so we have less hunting.
            pts_in_this_poly.append(pt.geometry)
            pts = pts.drop([j])

    # We could do all sorts, like grab a property of the
    # points, but let's just append the number of them.
    pts_in_polys.append(len(pts_in_this_poly))

# Add the number of points for each poly to the dataframe.
polygons['number of points'] = gpd.GeoSeries(pts_in_polys)
```